# Access Denied on PowerShell Running Disable-ScheduledTask as Admin

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to simply disable a Task Scheduler Task through PowerShell but getting access denied. I'm running PS as Admin, and I am a local Admin. I can successfully run the command on another box that is running the same set of scheduled tasks for a different environment but I can't for the life of me figure out what is different here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is by any chance the task schedule configured to use a specific user account which is different than the one you're running powershell from?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it happened but had to delete and recreate every task to regain access for ANY user (even service accounts), seems as though they got corrupted somehow.